# How to set value in select Input React admin?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

How can I set value to the `SelectInput` so that I can update value in `react-admin`?

Below is my code.
I am not able to update the value using `initialValue`.
On each update, I will get updated value (id of selected input) in state  `selectedSkillDetails[0].skill_id`. I can set value initially but can't update the `initialValue`.

I think `initialValue` will not be a good method for updation.
Please suggest a solution.
Thanks in advance

```js
<ReferenceInput
  onChange={employeeSkill => onSkillChange(employeeSkill)}
  source="skill_id"
  reference="skill_master"
  label="Skill"
  initialValue={
    selectedSkillDetails[0] ? selectedSkillDetails[0].skill_id : undefined
  }
>
  <SelectInput optionText="name" validate={required()} />
</ReferenceInput>
```

Comment: Yes, for `react-admin`, the `initialValue` just like `defaultValue` cannot be updated because they are only used if the `value` is `undefined or '' or null`.   What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why would you want to update the `initialValue` when a value can be picked for the `SelectInput`?

Comment: Actually I want to update the value of select input.  On each action I will get the selected id of values in the drop down. which is stored in the state   selectedSkillDetails[0].skill_id  so I want to update the value of select input using this state.